# compiled JiBX classes not in EAR file

Tags: websphere, java-ee-6, jibx

I try to run a JiBX mapping on a WebSphere Application Server 8.
I compile the binding with ant in Eclipse.

When I run the application as "Java Application" then no errors occur.
But when I create an ear-File of the project and deploy it on application server then I get the Exception that the binding is not compiled.

The WAR file in the ear file does not contain the JIBX_bidning..._acces.classes. How can I get a correct ear package of my project, that also runs on server?

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veote,

You are probably using eclipse for development. Eclipse auto-compiles the source files without binding the schema into the compiled class files.

You have a few options:

- Use the [JiBX eclipse plugin](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/eclipse/index.html).
- or - Package your class files in a jar so eclipse can't change them before adding to the war file.
- or - Use the jibx-maven-plugin which works great with eclipse and WebSphere.

Good Luck!

Don

Comment: Thanks I will try, but is there a way to compile the binding from code? I know the JiBX has a Compile class.